# Get id or class name in jquery selector use regex by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I'm trying to catch all the id and class name in the selector by PHP

here's the regex which I'm using:

```
/(?:\$|\$_|.(?:find|prependTo|closest|addClass|removeClass|toggleClass))+\(\'(.*?)\'\)/
```

it works for

```
$('#test')
$('#test .banana')
```

it'll give me `#test` and `#test .banana` *(I can use PHP to split them by space)*

but it couldn't use on the following selector

```
$('.photo-preview[temp-id="' + Index + '"]')
$('.photo-preview[temp-id="' + Index + '"] .hello')
```

it'll just **catch the whole content not class name only**,

is there any way to catch the class name?

--

EDIT: has no answer yet, so I decide use this two regex until there's a really answer

```
(?:\.|#)-?([_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(?=[^\(]*\))
```

*explain: Find all the ids and classes*

```
(?:\$|\$_|.(?:addClass|removeClass|toggleClass))\(\'([_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-].*(?=[^\(]*\'\)))
```

*explain: Find those class names in addClass(), removeClass() .. blah blah*

*because they have no dot or # symbols when use addClass()*

--

Now mix them together as one regex by "|" (OR)

**HERE'S THE TEMPORARY ANSWER**

```
(?:\.|#)-?([_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(?=[^\(]*\))|(?:\$|\$_|.(?:addClass|removeClass|toggleClass))\(\'([_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-].*(?=[^\(]*\'\)))
```

**BECAREFUL:** this will catch . and # symbols, and even "addClass('" 
string,

so you need to choose the right array, and split or the unnecessary symbols by PHP.

**HOLD ON:** THIS WILL CATCH ".jpg" TOO, STILL EDITING ..

Comment: Could you load some test body data into http://regex101.com and save, and share the link for us to fork please?

Comment: here https://regex101.com/r/hU0cU8/1

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just posted another question here:
*[There must something before the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413812/there-must-something-before-the-string/28414000?noredirect=1#comment45163575_28414000)*

And I think I get the answer.

**BE WARE: please mind some regex will capture `.` and `#` symbols, and some won't**

--

## 1.Get IDs and classes in selectors

**ANSWER**

you still couldn't get class name in addClass(), removeClass() though ..

```
/(?:(?:\$|\$_|\.(?:find|prependTo|closest))\(\'|(?<!^)\G)\s?([.#][-\w]+)?[^()\s.#]*(?=[^()]*\))/gm
```

*[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oV7dF3/1)*

--

### Explain

#### A little trick

```
(?:(?:\$|\$_|\.(?:find|prependTo|closest))\(\'|(?<!^)\G)
```

This is a little trick to confirm the ID or class in in a selector,

so **you won't** get `.jpg` in `url(http://www.google.com/test.jpg)`,

but the bad news is, you need to add them manually when there's a new selector

#### Don't want to capture . and #?

You just need to remove `[.#]` in the regex, so you need to change

```
/(?:(?:\$|\$_|\.(?:find|prependTo|closest))\(\'|(?<!^)\G)\s?([.#][-\w]+)?[^()\s.#]*(?=[^()]*\))/gm
                                                              ^^^
                                                      Remove this bracket
```

--

## 2.Get classes in addClass(), removeClass()..

**ANSWER**

This will capture the whole content inside `addClass`, `removeClass` and `toggleClass`,

it's the dumbness way as far as I know.

```
/(?:\.(?:addClass|removeClass|toggleClass))\('(.*?)'\)/g
```

*[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oV7dF3/1)*

--

## 3.Get IDs and class in CSS

**ANSWER**

```
/(?![^{]+})(?:\.|#)([_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/g
```

*[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oK9fM0/2)*

--

## The answer of this question?

Let's collect the first and second regex

```
/(?:(?:\$|\$_|\.(?:find|prependTo|closest))\(\'|(?<!^)\G)\s?([-\w]+)?[^()\s.#]*(?=[^()]*\))|(?:\.(?:addClass|removeClass|toggleClass))\('(.*)'\)/g
```

so you can now get IDs and classes in selectors,

and you still need to split classes in addClass(), removeClass() in other way.

*[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sR1sU3/1)*