# There must something before the string

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I'm using PHP and trying to catch all the IDs & classes in jQuery's selector like:

```
$('#ddd .aaa #bbb #c').show();
test.$('#eee[type=submit] .fff').addClass('test')
```

but [my regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408551/get-id-or-class-name-in-jquery-selector-use-regex-by-php?noredirect=1#comment45156550_28408551) will catch '.jpg', '.png' .. url too, now I have another idea

"there must a `$('` symbol in front of any class name or id"

*(So it won't catch any URL link or hex code)*

--

[Here's what I do](https://regex101.com/r/qE3wW5/4):

```
\$\('((?:\.|#)([_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*))(?=[^\(]*\))
```

but it'll only catch the first match

```
#ddd
#eee
```

how can I get each classes name or IDs like:

```
#ddd
.aaa
#bbb
#c
#eee
.fff
```

*and keep(or repeat?) the rule: there must a `$('` symbols in front of the string.*

--

**Answer:**

This regex will search the classes and IDs in `$()`, `.find()`, `.prependTo()`, `.closest()`,

so you need to add more selector manually:

```
/(?:(?:\$|\$_|\.(?:find|prependTo|closest))\(\'|(?<!^)\G)\s?([.#][-\w]+)?[^()\s.#]*(?=[^()]*\))/gm
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead of regex.

Comment: I'm making a random class name system, 

so I want to get the all class names and IDs,

then I can generate a random name for them and replace them.

Comment: For 'there must be something before' you need to use positive lookbehind assertion: '(?<=pattern)'. For you case it would be `(?<=\$\(\'). Read more here for example: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/advanced-regular-expression-tips-and-techniques--net-11011

Comment: I tried positive lookbehind before, but I can't use `|` symbol in it, it gave me a `Lookbehind assertion is not fixed width` error, because I have different `header` (like: `$_('`, `.find('` ) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`\G`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) anchor here. The anchor `\G` matches at the position where the previous match ended. During the first match attempt, `\G` matches at the start of the string in the way `\A` does.

```
(?:\$\('|(?<!^)\G)\s?([.#]\w+)[^()\s.#]*(?=[^()]*\))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qE3wW5/8)

Comment: It matched something which is not class(.xxx) or ID(#xxx)

Comment: see this https://regex101.com/r/qE3wW5/7 , And it won't match `(.xxx) or ID(#xxx)` . Please do a recheck.

Comment: I'm feel sorry for my English, and you are really doing well,

the problem is `$('#aaa .bbb ccc')` will give me `#aaa .bbb ccc` but I want `#aaa .bbb` only

Comment: I tested it with `$('.aa.bb .cc #dd ee #hh')`, and it stops from `ee`, so it only gives me `.aa .bb .cc #dd` but I expect `.aa .bb .cc #dd #hh`

Comment: I just spent a hour on researching your regex, and it works very well, I really appreciate your help, and I found the last problem, `#test-hello` will only capture `#test`,
so I change `([.#]\w+)` to `([.#][-\w]+)` and everything works fine, really appreciate it.